# Objective-C block OS X system shutdown to do some work for an unknown time

Tags: objective-c, macos, interrupt, dialog, system-shutdown

First of all, I am new to Objective-C. So please be patient to me :)

I need to do some tasks for an unknown time (like: backup data to NAS) before OS X Mavericks shuts down by users choice.
So i need a solution to cancel that shutdown.

I already tried:

```
- (NSApplicationTerminateReply)applicationShouldTerminate:(NSApplication *)sender
{
    return NSTerminateCancel;
}
```

Now the system shutdown shows a Message to the User, that my app blocks the shutdown.
I dont want to let the user see that message. How do i catch that message and answer it with "Cancel" ??
I read about the SIGTERM and SIGKILL Signals. But it seems that Apple doesn't want to let them intercept somehow.
Is there a better way to interrupt/cancel the Shutdown and do some work before Shutdown?

Thanks for any advice, tips and solutions!

Comment: You can add signal handler for SIGTERM, but you can't catch SIGKILL.

Comment: You should reconsider your problem: it is a bad style to abort an user's command without to inform him/her.

Comment: I can totally understand your objection.That's the reason why i created the GUI which appears after that. In that GUI, the user can choose what he want's to do. "Shutdown" or "Backup and Shutdown". Maybe it's possible to rework the "Shutdown" button? Instead of shutting down, to start my app? That would solve my problem to cancel that shutdown. Is this possible? I know that wouldn't be a clean way to solve my problem, but it would be a possible way.

Comment: To be honest, I don't want to use your app if it will behave like that. If user wishes to shut down his machine you cannot block that operation and print some message. That's really poor User Experience. 
What's more: Even Apple is not doing it this way unless operation is system-critial (like updating the whole OS).

Comment: in general i am on your opinion. But that's an discussion not about this thread. I am willing to discus that with you offtopic. I already programmed that for Windows Systems. We've got 10.000 Users who needs that and they want exactly that solution. I dont do an backup at the Shutdown Cancel. But a very system critical task which cant be done if the user works on his PC, so i need to do that on shutdown! The backup task was just an imagination to be easier for this discussion. Please back to Topic!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [logout hook](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16825/make-a-script-app-run-on-logout). They're deprecated, but they still work. The user will see a grey screen until your script finishes running.

Comment: i already tried to use logout hook. Thats not what i am looking for due to the user has to interact with an gui which appears. After the user did his choice in that gui, my app decides what to backup and after it, my app shuts down the system.

Comment: ok. i have tried logouthook. For me, there is one issue. There is just a grey Screen. The Users dont know what their MACs are doing. I need to show them some kind of an progress bar or something. Do you have any suggestions how to solve it ? Is there any chance to let an GUI come up at the logouthook.